# How to automate Expo web index.html styling

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web

EDIT: I returned to a managed workflow, please test any future answers yourself and report back.

I have an ejected (Bare Workflow) Expo React Native app. I am currently working on the web version using react-native-web.

**THE PROBLEM**

The expo build:web command automatically overwrites the web index.html file with styling that causes my root element views to scroll, while any VirtualizedLists adopt weird styling patterns. Therefore each time I build, I must manually go into the web index.html file and replace the code with [this styling recommended from react-native-web](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/setup/#root-element), which works perfectly:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { overflow: hidden; }
#root { display:flex; height:100%; }
```

**THE ASK**

Is there any way to automate or define this behavior and replace all this Expo styling with the react-native-web styling? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`npx expo customize:web` then select the file you want to generate. In your case `web/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `expo customize:web` and select `web/index.html`.

It'll create a file named `web/index.html`. Edit it as you wish.

To revert to the default `.html` file, delete `web/index.html` and run `expo start --clear`

Comment: Anything else I need to change? Expo doesn't pick up the changes in web/index.html

Comment: The changes in web/index.html doesn't effect anything. Does anybody knows what to setup exactly to receive changes?

Answer (score 0):

After some researches and read the Expo docs here: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/#static-files . Figured out to override the `index.html` it needs to be created manually an `public/index.html`. Copy the content of `web/index.html` into the new created
`index.html` and make your changes in that. After rebundle with `npx expo start --web` the changes would be visible.